# In MacBook Terminal login history, does console mean that someone physically logged into my MacBook?

Tags: macos, terminal, security, login, console

In terminal, I used the last command and got the following:

```
Paul  console                   Tue May 11 15:46 - 15:49  (00:03)
paul  console                   Tue May 11 09:17 - 09:18  (00:01)
```

I wasn’t at my computer at that time. Someone else was using my computer with a different username. Does this mean that someone physically logged into my computer under the username paul when I wasn’t there?

Comment: Is there a user account called "Paul" on your Mac? Who uses that normally?

Answer (score 0):

These login sessions can also appear during a short wakeup from sleep from certain programs that initiate a new session. Or was your computer supposed to be completely off?

Comment: My computer was supposed to be on and someone else logged in under their own username.